# Create email with Exchange Web Services (can't find CreateItemType)

Tags: c#, web-services, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to create an application that using EWS can create a letter in the mailbox.
Found an article on msdn, which seems to do what I need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563009(v=exchg.140).aspx, 
but got an error  `The type or namespace name 'CreateItemType' could not be found` at `CreateItemType createItemRequest = new CreateItemType();`

In my code i use `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll` and `using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;` - but there no such type.

I was finding a few topics on stackoverflow, which used a similar code, but did not understand where to find the missing type.

May be I use the wrong dll? Or should use other 'using' directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article that you pointed to uses the auto-generated proxy classes, so if you want to continue down that path, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408522(v=exchg.140).aspx to set up your project. But I wouldn't recommend that.

Instead, use the EWS Managed API, which is what your dll and the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data namespace are designed for. For a code sample that uses the EWS Managed API to create an email, go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600185(v=exchg.150).aspx or here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600292(v=exchg.150).aspx.

Or go here to find a bunch of prepackaged code samples (so you can see all the context): http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=User&f%5B0%5D.Value=Microsoft%20Office%20Developer%20Documentation%20Team&f%5B1%5D.Type=Topic&f%5B1%5D.Value=email%20items.